# calling multiple text files with different names at a time in matlab program. These text files are saved in a folder

Tags: matlab

I have around 2000 at2 files saved in a folder. All files have different name. Each file contain data of earthquake. So i have to determine parameters for each earthquake.I have to write a single program in which I can calculate all parameters for every earthquake file.For that i have to call 2000 text files in matlab program. How can I call these files all having different names in matlab program?
Also I have to skip first 4 lines in each text file because those represent header lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dir](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function. Assume all files are in directory `foo`. Then something like this would work -

```
listing = dir('foo')
for i = 1:length(listing)
     if ~isdir(listing(i))
         apply_your_function(listing(i).name)
     end
end
```